# Response get HTML applied and status 500 when a Exception occurs for a none localhost request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am are using a custom action invocation for some special requests

```
try
{
    controller.ActionInvoker = new RemoteMethodInvoker();
    (controller as IController).Execute(requestContext); // calls MVC controller method
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    var errorResponse = new RemoteErrorResponse(request, exception, session);
    errorResponse.Write(httpContext.Response);
}
finally
{
    _factory.ReleaseController(controller);
    httpContext.Items.Remove(RemoteRequest.RequestKey);
}
```

For a localhost user the response looks like below with status 200

```
{
  "type": "exception",
  "message": "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.",
  "where": "",
  "tid": 40
}
```

But for a none localhost user the status changes to 500 and some html is already applied to the response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
    </h2>
</body>
</html>{
  "type": "exception",
  "message": "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.",
  "where": "",
  "tid": 40
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea where this happens or how I can get around this.